# mySQL UPDATE table based on SELECT (count) of a different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of classes, and a table of subjects.

```
CLASS
|class_id|class_name|subject_id|date_time|
------------------------------------------
(imagine some rows here)

SUBJECT
|subject_id|subject_name|current_class_count|
---------------------------------------------
(imagine some rows here)
```

For indexing purposes I'd like to update the list of subjects every hour with the list of classes which have a `date_time` greater than right now.

I can do a select statement like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS num, subject_id
FROM class
GROUP BY subject_id
where date_time > NOW()
```

and I will get something like

```
RESULT
|num|subject_id|
----------------
| 8 |        1 |
| 6 |        2 |
| 9 |        3 |
----------------
```

What's the most efficient way to get the subject table updated with the `current_class_count`? I could do this with PHP by looping through and doing several update statements, but I think mySql should have an easier way.

Comment: Have you looked into using triggers?

Comment: Can you post actual tables definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:  How about this:

```
UPDATE SUBJECT
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT count(*) AS num, subject_id
FROM class
GROUP BY subject_id
where date_time > NOW()) AS t ON SUBJECT.subject_id = t.subject_id
SET SUBJECT.current_class_count = coalesce( t.num, 0 )
```

As long as I've typed it right, basically you should be able to run this once an hour and it will update your SUBJECT table.

Joining a table in an UPDATE statement is a bit different in MySQL compared to Microsoft SQL.  Here is a link about it:

http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html

Comment: I'm not positive but I don't think you can use a LEFT JOIN on an UPDATE command in mySQL. I tried it anyhow but I'm getting an "error near FROM SUBJECT"

Comment: @cwd - my bad.  I forgot MySQL was a bit different in the syntax.  I updated my post and put a link on how the syntax works.

Comment: It won't update subjects for which last class just ended, its count will stay indefinitely > 0. You really need left join and `coalesce( t.num, 0 )` instead of `t.num` in the last line.

Comment: @piotrm - Good point.  I thought about that but then forgot to address it in my statement.  I'll add it in.

Comment: Almost perfect now, but still it has to be LEFT JOIN, coalesce is just to deal with NULL t.num that left join can possibly produce, which will happen exactly after passing max class date for given section or for sections without any class. I would also add index on (subject_id, date_time) in the class table and its the fastest possible, correct solution.

Comment: @piotrm - Yep, I forgot to update that area as well.  Good catch.  Thanks.