# Calculate average message quality per user in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Consider the following tables:

```
users                    messages
-------------------      ----------------------
user_id avg_quality      msg_id user_id quality
-------------------      ----------------------
1                        1      1       1
2                        2      1       0
3                        3      1       0
                         4      1       1
                         5      1       1
                         6      2       0
                         7      2       0
                         8      3       1
```

`messages.quality` is either `0` or `1`. I need to calculate the average message quality per user and update `users.avg_quality` accordingly. So the desired output would be modified `users` table like so:

```
users
-------------------
user_id avg_quality  <-- DECIMAL (8,2)
-------------------
1       0.60         <-- (3x1 + 2x0) / 5
2       0.00         <-- (2x0) / 2
3       1.00         <-- (1x1) / 1
```

I've begun my query like this, I know the syntax is incorrect but have no better idea. Do you?

```
UPDATE messages m, users u
SET avg_quality = (SELECT COUNT(m.msg_id) / SUM(m.quality))
WHERE m.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: You might do this in one run possibly, see this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209215/mysql-update-table-based-on-select-count-of-a-different-table The answers currently posting are getting the data but not updating the users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE users u
       INNER JOIN (SELECT a.user_id, AVG(quality) avg_quality 
                   FROM messages a
                        INNER JOIN users b
                            ON a.user_id = b.user_id
                   GROUP BY a.user_id
                  ) tmp
                  ON u.user_id = tmp.user_id
SET u.avg_quality = tmp.avg_quality;
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I run it, it affects zero rows?

Comment: Hi, see a possible solution for 0s in my post.

Comment: check internal select query first.

Comment: @Omesh - the mistake was mine...typo. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

See the average function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Your select should be something like this:

```
select user_id, AVG(quality) from messages group by user_id
```

If you begin with an empty users table you could run a query like this one to update it all:

```
insert into users (user_id, avg_quality)
select m.user_id, coalesce(AVG(m.quality),0) from messages m group by m.user_id
```

If you need continuous results Luc's proposal will work for you:

```
update users u left join (
    select m.user_id, AVG(m.quality) as average from messages m group by m.user_id  
) as average_result_t on u.user_id = average_result_t.user_id
set u.average = coalesce(average_result_t.average,0)
```